# Access to a variable through all the components Angular2

Tags: angular, scope

Currently, after a user logs in, I get as a response an object that represents all of the user data (doing the authentication on auth-guard service - external .ts function), and then I know which component to render by canActivate =[AuthGuard]).

Problem is, I need to have access to this object through all my site components, so I know what to render in each component, and as far as I know you can't pass data through router-outlet.

So how can I access this object from any of the components? Any way to make it global in some way? Saving it to cookie won't help me as I can't let the user touch it.

Comment: Store the user data in a service provided in your root NgModule. Inject the service in every service/component/pipe/directive that needs to access this information.

Comment: Yep,wasn't aware of injection. Its exactly what I wanted. Ty

Comment: then take a big step back, and read the documentation, or a good book about Angular. DI is at the heart of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your auth-guard service where you make that auth call store the object in a variable and provide it in the main app module. Then you can inject it anywhere you need it. However, in order to make it a singleton service, it would only be provided at the root level.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService {

  public myObj: object;

  public authGuardFunction() {
    // do stuff
   this.myObj = result;
  }    
}
```

In your components:

```
@Component({
 ...
})
export class SomeComopnent implements OnInit {

  public myProp: object;

  constructor(private authGuardService: AuthGuardService ) {
    this.myProp= this.authGuardService.myObj;
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Wasn't sure how (: Thanks!

Comment: The only difference in you code and my code is i gave the idea you gave the code 

Comment: @MrJSingh indeed, but its always nice to see an example :) thanks

Comment: this works , problem is that I set "myProp" using an ajax, which means it takes a second. and then instead of injecting what I need it just inject undefined as myProp ... idea how to delay the injection?

Comment: ok I just did an interval that keep checking the value and set it when it has a value.

Comment: @Ben you could also you ngIf or check for value with the OnChange lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a service to achieve this. You can have a global service in your root component and then access to all child component and then just get data through that service in each component you want.